# Cannot disable read access the Windows 7 security log

Tags: windows, account-security, windows-server, group-policy

So we have some Windows 7 systems with some security requirements. I am trying to disable read access the security log.  The command “wevtutil gl security” shows a result of the following:

> channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x7;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)

From what little I know of these things, I am thinking that the “(A;;0x3;;;IU)” is giving interactive users read and write of the log (they cannot clear it)

What puzzles me is that the command

> wevtutil sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x7;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)

shows immediate results on our normal windows 7 PC’s, but it does NOTHING on the machines in question.  The command runs, gives no error, but “wevtutil gl security” still shows the “(A;;0x3;;;IU)” in the channelAccess string.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you hamstrung by a group policy?  Attempting to modify the settings of the security log from a local or remote cmd line when a group policy is enforcing the settings will result in you typing the cmd and getting no results....forever......and that's a very long time.